# Wordpress User Data sent through cURL

Tags: wordpress, curl, user-data

I've just integrated the marketing tool Klaviyo with our Wordpress/WooCommerce set up and I'm trying to push user meta data through a cURL API - but failing!

You can find out how the API works here: https://www.klaviyo.com/docs/http-api#people

I'm hoping to add an action so when the user profile saves, it hooks in my function sending the meta data through to Klaviyo.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong please - code below?

Thanks so much in advance.

Linz

```
<?php

// Hook into the action which saves the User Meta Data (written by LD)

add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'klaviyo_send' );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'klaviyo_send' );

function klaviyo_send () {

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/identify?data=eyJ0b2tlbiI6ICJoYXFYaXEiLCAicHJvcGVydGllcyI6IHsiJGVtYWlsIjogInRob21hcy5qZWZmZXJzb25AZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCAiJGxhc3RfbmFtZSI6ICJKZWZmZXJzb24iLCAiUGxhbiI6ICJUcmlhbCIsICJTaWduIFVwIERhdGUiOiAiMjAxMy0wMS0yNyAxMjoxNzowNiIsICIkZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6ICJUaG9tYXMifX0=',
CURLOPT_POST => 1,
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
    'token' => 'haqXiq', //This is the public 'key' in Klaviyo
    '$email' => $user_id->email, //This translates the wordpress field into the Klaviyo field
    'twitter' => $user_id->twitter,
)
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending data by this way .. change the posted data to url friendly ways like `?key=value&key=value&key=value`

```
  //extract data from the post
    //set POST variables
    $url = 'https://a.klaviyo.com/api/identify?data=eyJ0b2tlbiI6ICJoYXFYaXEiLCAicHJvcGVydGllcyI6IHsiJGVtYWlsIjogInRob21hcy5qZWZmZXJzb25AZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCAiJGxhc3RfbmFtZSI6ICJKZWZmZXJzb24iLCAiUGxhbiI6ICJUcmlhbCIsICJTaWduIFVwIERhdGUiOiAiMjAxMy0wMS0yNyAxMjoxNzowNiIsICIkZmlyc3RfbmFtZSI6ICJUaG9tYXMifX0=';
    $fields = array(
        'token' => 'haqXiq', //This is the public 'key' in Klaviyo
        '$email' => $user_id->email, //This translates the wordpress field into the Klaviyo field
        'twitter' => $user_id->twitter,
    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks Prakash! I'll give it a go tomorrow (super late here in London!) and let you know how I get on!